# Write values to file by columns

Tags: java, file-writing

I need to generate table data and write it to file.
Output file should look like:

```
123|aaaa|bbba|
124|aaab|bbbb|
125|aaac|bbbc|
```

It's easy to do it by generating a single row, like **123|aaaa|bbba|\n** and write it, but I need to generate a single **column** because of generator has performance issues, write it, then generate another one.

In the for loop I need to write to file something like:

```
123|
124|
125|
```

Then:

```
123|aaaa|
124|aaab|
125|aaac|
```

And finally:

```
123|aaaa|bbba|
124|aaab|bbbb|
125|aaac|bbbc|
```

My current code look like:

```
os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
StringBuffer column = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < numberofcolumns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        column.append(columns[i].genValue());
        column.append("|\n");
    }
    os.write(column.toString().getBytes(), 0, entry.length());
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your current output?

Comment: Any solution will be absolutely inefficient. Make what you can to avoid writing column by column as it's very complex. It's much better to write each column to another file and at the end concatenate those files.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like to write it instantly into a file and reopen it every time? 
What about saving it internally and after all data has been generated, write it to the file?

You could declare a three dimensional array and write the data into it.
After you've finished this, write the array to the file. Should be much much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like a bad idea, but could be achieved with `paste` :

```
$ echo """a
> b
> c
> d""" > testFile

$ echo """1
> 2
> 3
> 4""" | paste -d"|" testFile - > modifiedFile

$ cat modifiedFile
a|1
b|2
c|3
d|4
```

Why it looks like a bad idea :

- While your generator can be slow, I doubt the number of columns to output is the throttle : it's most probably the data retrieval / filtering / etc. that slows down the operation.
- Can you be sure the data of each column will be returned in the same order?
- Rewriting the file each time you get a new column is very slow. Couldn't you store the data from each column in memory (i.e. a bash array?) and write the file once you're done?